# alternative IDE for squeak/pharo

Tags: ide, smalltalk

I've been using smalltalk for a while now and I love the language and the concept. What I just hate is the System browser. This tool doesn't even resemble a modern IDE. How am I supposed to code without tabs, outlines and handy shortcuts? I often find myself implementing a selector and noticing that it would be nice to isolate a piece of code in a separate (private) selector, just for readability shake, but I don't. Because it takes like 5 mouse clicks and I have to navigate away from the selector I am working at, and navigate back to it. Oh wait, I can't! Because it has syntax errors, because I haven't finished it yet! Kills me. And I don't have a 24 inch display to open 3 browsers.

Sorry for a little rant. My question is, is there a real IDE (Eclipse, Net.Beans, VS) for smalltalk? Maybe for some commercial version of smalltalk?

Comment: Instead of ranting, you might want to make your navigation and ide problems more clear. What makes the eclipse outline different from the protocol/selectors lists in the browser? What makes tabs different from several open browsers (you have the tab nav in the bottom in pharo). What handy shortcuts do you need? And how do you want a reasonable extract method refactoring to work with unparseable code in any ide. The squeak/pharo browser has shortcomings but your rant does not make sense.

Comment: Browser's outline doesn't show instance variables, for example. And you cannot take a glance on several selectors from different classes bacause it's not tree-based. You have to use the mouse a lot. Tabs would make selector's code and protocol/selector list independent. I don't need the refactoring you mention, I just don't want to use the mouse that much. In a normal text editor I would create a new method with a few quick keystrokes doing some copy-paste.

Comment: The browser outline shouldn't show instance variables. That's an implementation detail.

Comment: @StephanEggermont: so are classes ;)

Comment: Completely agree - every time I get back to Pharo (haven't done that in a while, though), editing text is just so different from what I'm used to in eclipse or any "normal" text editor that it's just very jarring. People I've convinced to give Pharo a try have failed at the same hurdle, and delving into the Squeak-guts to try and fix it is just too time consuming. [GemDev](http://karpisek.net/gemdev/) looked like it was coming up with some [great features](http://karpisek.net/gemdev-help/news.html) to merge eclipse and GemStone, but it seems to have stagnated a few years back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically, the real "IDE" is the Smalltalk one, and one could claim that the others are just an adaptation to the limits of traditional textual programming languages (not rethorical, just check out the evolution of typical development environment UIs and how they are adding features that exists in Smalltalk from the very beggining, like the senders and references in VS).

Just a side note: actually more than 2000 open-source projects in the [SqueakSource](http://www.squeaksource.com) repository were coded without tabs, outlines and shortcuts (I think still in Squeak you can cross reference any text selecting and pressing with Alt-6). I can't tell you how sad I feel when I must to go back to file based developement, still don't understand why most developers love to sweep text, mess with line numbers and page up-down files in directories. The good news for you, is that you have many options:

There is an alternative browser called [BobsBrowser](http://www.squeaksource.com/BobsBrowser.html) (works in Pharo 1.3) which lets you browse

- Class hierarchy windows exploring each class
- System Category window
- Unsaved edits
- Recent classes
- Recent methods
- Method categories for instances and classes
- Unsent methods
- Driller relating every structural information
- etc.

The advantage over the Whisker browser is that the hierarchical lists are attached to a window while in BobsBrowser you can detach them.

It all depends of the different activities you're performing when you're developing. With some experience in Smalltalk you'll find that you prefer some browser for exploratory insights and others for refactorings, etc. BobsBrowser for example is good for knowledge organization or custom navigation of Smalltalk classes and categories, the hierarchies you can see are the organizations from the Smalltalk reflective meta-architecture at any level (classes, senders, implementors), and they are expandable/collapsable (in the classic system browsers you can only expand the system categories and subcategories).

The instance variables were shown historically in the Smalltalk/V flavors, and there is an old goodie (from Squeak 2.7 IIRC) to enable it back again but almost nobody today maintains the classic System Browser in Squeak/Pharo. Adding that feature to [OmniBrowser](http://bergel.eu/download/OmnibrowserReference.pdf) would be more complicated though because is a browser framework (as every serious framework, it took some time to learn it for the first time), although the effort of the Squeak/Pharo community is absolutely incredible, still the Smalltalk community needs more developers.

You have also a [commercial Smalltalk](http://www.lesser-software.com/lswvst.htm) which isn't public (downloadable) yet but includes [IDE-like features](http://www.lesser-software.com/images/Screenshots/lswvst/LSWVST_Vista.jpg) of traditional programming environments

Answer (score 6):

You might want to check out [tODE](http://code.google.com/p/tode/). It's at a very early stage, but it is an attempt to provide a Smalltalk IDE in the web-browser and is a break from the traditional Smalltalk IDE. With that said, I don't think you'd want to start using tODE right away, but you can keep an eye on it as it evolves.

Dale

Comment: Already seen that. Looks promising for work on remote images. Keep the good work!

Answer (score 6):

- Pharo is trying to have the [Nautilus Browser](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24369478/ESUG-Nautilus-Award.m4v) ready for Pharo
  1.4. I suspect there will be a flood of awesome new tools as the system stabilizes over the next few releases.
- There's the [Glamorous Inspector](http://www.humane-assessment.com/blog/glamorous-inspector-for-smalltalk).
- [Spoon has been mounted as a WebDAV filesystem](http://thiscontext.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/my-favorite-text-editor-editing-a-spoon-webdav-filesystem/), so you can use whatever tool you like. Spoon is not another Smalltalk, but a testbed for revolutionary Smalltalk technology, which can be incorporated into any other Smalltalk (it's currently on top of Squeak)
- There is the [Tiling Window Manager](http://magaloma.blogspot.com/2011/05/tiling-window-manager.html) to help you organize
- Since Squeak and Pharo are live, dynamic, open systems powered only by volunteers, anyone sufficiently motivated can create the next generation of tools ;-)

p.s. I feel your pain. The 20-browsers-open thing is a drag. Let's invent the future!

Answer (score 2):

> And I don't have a 24 inch display to open 3 browsers.

You could give the [Whisker Browser](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/study/courses/OMP/public/software/sqcdrom2/Packages/Tools/Whisker/index.html) a try. It lays out the methods side-by-side so that you don't have to position all these windows manually.

[image: Whisker Browser]

I played with it a few years ago but I'm not sure what state it's in right now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how mature it is, but the [Etoile project](http://etoileos.com) has an IDE called CodeMonkey for writing Smalltalk applications.  It's not specifically for Squeak, and instead uses their own smalltalk implementation, but it may be worth looking into.  Unfortunately, it's only available in their SVN repository, so it's a pain to compile and install.